# Difference of magnitude of unit vectors?

Tags: vectors

The question is that there are two unit vectors whose sum is also a unit vector , what will be the difference of their magnitude ( of the two vectors).
The answer is $\sqrt{3}$, should not difference of magnitude of two unit vector be zero? Because a unit vector would have it magnitude equal to 1, so 1-1=0 , why the difference is $\sqrt{3}$

Comment: The magnitude of the difference is $\sqrt 3$. The difference between the magnitudes is $0$, like you say.

Comment: The "difference in their magnitudes" and the "magnitude of their difference" are two different things: in general $\|\vec u - \vec v\| \ne \|\vec u\| - \|\vec v\|$, They will only be equal when the two vectors are parallel (not just in the same line, but pointing in the same direction).